# How to compare different queries without autotrace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different queries and I want to compare there performance in order to decide which one to use. I'm currently using Oracle SQL developer and SQL Server 2012.

I can't auto trace with this DB because its greyed out in SQL Developer. I never had this problem. Usually, I just compared the consistent_gets in the auto trace.

What do you suggest to compare the queries?

Could I export the schema for the db and just input into my own server? I should be access to auto trace, I would assume. Would you suggest this? Is there an easy way to export the scheme for all tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the [Execution Plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)'s of both queries. In the SQL Mgmt Studio you can use the UI to get an execution plan rather than execute the query.

You can also use the [SHOWPLAN SET options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get XML or Text explanation of the execution plan.

Also refer to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan) which has some interesting info (accepted answer).